# Комбинации из регулярных выражений Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Я не могу понять, каким образом комбинировать регулярные выражения при использовании метода `.matches`.

Например, `s.matches("([0-9]+)([a-z]+)")` определяет символы `1z` но символы `z1` он не видит. Как сделать, чтобы проверялся произвольный порядок выражений. К примеру, сначала первое будет искать соответствия по всему тексту, потом второе по всему и т.д.

Comment: Таких соответствий будет много. Нужно найти сначала одну группу символов, потом другую и т.д.

Comment: А можете привести более конкретные условия? Из чего и что надо получить?

Comment: правильно я понимаю, что так будет поиск по символам от 0 до 9 и a-z с 1+ вхождений? Прекрасно, спасибо)

Comment: в данном случае полное совпадение найдет 1z, первая группа найдет 1, вторая группа z .... в чем вопрос то?

Comment: в этом и был. я всё понял, спасибо большое

Comment: А в чём разобрались? Может, просто удалите этот "вопрос", который понятен только вам, если не хотите объяснять, в чём тут проблема.

Comment: Многие люди, хорошо разбирающиеся в каком-либо вопросе(тут "Регулярные выражения") воспринимают такие вещи как само собой разумеещееся... Для меня этот вариант не являлся таковым. Теперь то  суть формирования выражений более очевидной стала. Сам до этого я  не догадался. Если Вы настаиваете, я могу удалить этот вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого существует метасимвол альтернативы `|`

```
s.matches("([0-9]+)([a-z]+)|([a-z]+)([0-9]+)")
```

Найдёт совпадения и `1z` и `z1`

Answer (score 1):

Для условия **И** вместо дублирования регулярных подвыражений можно выполнить две проверки и использовать операторы языка программирования, на котором вы пишите.

```
if (Pattern.matches("[0-9]", s) && Pattern.matches("[a-z]", s)) {
    // строка s, содержащая хотя бы одну цифру И хотя бы одну букву
    ...
}
```

Обратите внимание, регулярные выражения были оптимизированы - убрана группировка и квантификатор `+`. Так как эти элементы не влияют на результат проверки.